# Disable access logging in s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have written python code that enables access logging in buckets.And I need to cancel last actions (disable access logging) via boto3  . But I searched it in boto3 docs and didn't find any solution of that . Is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable bucket logging, you should use an empty BucketLoggingStatus request element:

```
response = client.put_bucket_logging(
    Bucket='string',
    BucketLoggingStatus={},
    ExpectedBucketOwner='string'
)
```

---

Reference:

[Boto3 put_bucket_logging](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_logging)

Comment: Please mark the answer as 'Accepted'